# how do I install novacom in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, software-recommendation, java, touchpad

I have been attempting to install android os on an hp touchpad running the webos system.I m pretty much a newbie at this but I ve been trying to install the novacom driver into ubuntu and dont think I m doing it right...Has anyone done this before?can you tell me the simplest way to install novacom into ubuntu 12.04 because I m just not achievinh it I feel.It keeps telling me I ll see a palm,inc folder when the driver is installed correctly but I dont see that folder.Also after downloading it and doubleclicking the package I havent yet got the option to install it...I attempted once to hook the hp touchpad by usb after what i thought was a correct novacom install but the computer didnt recognize the touchpad so it couldnt have been right.Any help is much appreciated.I m running ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This may help you:** http://thehtd.blogspot.com/2013/03/installing-webos-sdk-on-ubuntu-linux.html

The article describes the installation of webOS SDK specific for the Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS on 32 bits.

Comment: I figured it out and your link is awesome information.When I ran this from a terminal on desktop it couldnt find the driver no matter what path Iset,however when i opened the folder where the novacom driver was then opened terminal from there it worked flawlessly